# Show that $ \lim_{R \rightarrow \infty } \oint_ {|z|=R} \frac{ 2z - 1 }{ z^{3} - 2z^{2} + 3z} = 0$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration

$ \lim_{R \rightarrow  \infty }  \oint_ {|z|=R}       \frac{ 2z - 1 }{ z^{3} - 2z^{2} + 3z} = 0$

I'm struggling with this problem. Could someone please help me figure out?

I have decomposed integrand into $-\frac{1}{3z} + \frac{z+4}{3(z^{2}-2z+3)}$ and I know that first term is always $-\frac{2 \pi i}{3}$ regardless of $R$ (or opposite sign when computed clockwise) but I don't know how to compute the next term.

Comment: The absolute value of the integrand is $\sim 2/R^2$, so ...

Comment: There is a trivial bound on the absolute value of a complex integral: the length of the curve times the maximum of the function on that curve. You can use it to show that this absolute value tends to $0$ when $R\to\infty$.

Comment: [Here's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3611409/123905) a discussion of a similar problem.  In your case, the leading order is $\frac{1}{z^2}$, whose residue I expect you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lvert z\rvert=R$ and $R$ is large enough, you have$$\left\lvert\frac{2z-1}{z^3-2z^2+3z}\right\rvert\leqslant\frac{2R+1}{R^3-R^2-3R}$$and therefore$$\left\lvert\oint_{\lvert z\rvert=R}\frac{2z-1}{z^3-2z^2+3z}\,\mathrm dz\right\rvert\leqslant2\pi R\frac{2R+1}{R^3-2R^2-3R}.$$Now, use the fact that$$\lim_{R\to\infty}2\pi R\frac{2R+1}{R^3-2R^2-3R}=0.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!

Comment: You need a factor of $2$ on the $R^2$ term.

Comment: @MarkViola I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos got it!